# Babel-node doesn't transform spread operator on preset env

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I'm trying to use babel-node with nodemon for the hot-reloading.
I've basically followed this [repo](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server).

My `dev` script in `package.json` looks like that:

```
"dev": "nodemon app.js --exec babel-node --presets env"
```

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Even though the spread operator is listed as supported by the env preset, when using it with this setup I get a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: What is your babel-cli version?

Comment: Mind to paste the code?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Install [`plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread).

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

then change your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: Is [`plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) now preferred, given that `plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` has not been updated in 4 years, and that the former is now mentioned on the babel registry, and included in `@babel/preset-env` (see [`available-plugins.js`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/src/available-plugins.js#L78)?

Comment: ^ Nevermind, I see this was updated 2 years ago (by Robin Wieruch, cool to see him here). Will update reference link text and address.

Comment: NOTE: This plugin is included in @babel/preset-env, in ES2018 so the plugin is not needed.